# Anonymity and Encryption networks feature and performance comparisons?

Tags: networking

Is there any independent feature comparison/benchmark between Anonymity and Encryption networks?
Some examples

- [I2P](http://www.i2p2.de/)
- [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/)
- Freenet

I found one [biased feature comparison](http://www.i2p2.de/how_networkcomparisons).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this paper](https://epub.uni-regensburg.de/7328/), titled "Performance Comparison of low-latency Anonymisation Services from a User Perspective" is a first start, there are several references in there.

The [Anonymity Bibliography](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/topic.html) is also a really good place to look for such information.